# Accessing a variable within a nested function of the same class

Tags: python, function, class, variables, scope

I am trying to access `variable` within `function_3` - how should I go about doing this?

```
class A:
    def function_1(self):
        
        def function_2(self):
            self.variable = 'Hello'
        function_2(self)
    
    function_1(self)

    def function_3(self):
        print(self.variable)
    
    function_3(self)
```

Comment: Do you get an error with the above code?

Comment: > NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

The name `self` from here `def function_2(self):` shadows name `self` from here `def function_1(self):`

```
class A:
    def function_1(self):
        def function_2(self): # Here name `self` shadows name `self` from previous line
            self.variable = 'Hello'

        function_2(self)

    function_1(self) # Here you have no `self` variable

    def function_3(self):
        print(self.variable)

    function_3(self) # Here you have no `self` variable too
```

I think you want to achieve this behavior

```
class A:
    def function_1(self):
        def function_2(x):
            x.variable = 'Hello'

        function_2(self)

    def function_3(self):
        print(self.variable)


a = A()
a.function_1()
a.function_3()
```

```
> Hello
```

Comment: Thank you, that is really helpful.

What if the class was defined ```class A(Frame)```?

Would you need to do ```a=A(Frame)```?

Comment: @BenjaminMcDowell I think you are talking about class inheritance, so `class A` is inherited from `class Frame`. In this case you also can do `a = A()`. If class `Frame` has some parameters in constructor, you should also pass it like `a = A("data", 42)`. Here more info about inheritance https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_inheritance.asp

Answer (score 0):

Shout out if I misunderstood what you want to do, but it looks like you need to create an instance of class A, with A(), and then calling function_1 and function_3 on that instance. Pardon all the jargon, but I hope you can learn from example below:

```py
class A:
    def function_1(self):
        def function_2(self):
            self.variable = 'Hello'

        function_2(self)


    def function_3(self):
        print(self.variable)



a = A()

a.function_1()
a.function_3()
```